# My Game Maker Character is glitching

Tags: game-maker

I have a liddle problem.
I'm programming a jump and run game with Game Maker Studio.
But the animation from the Character is glitching.
If I jump against the wall, my Character gets stuck in the wall and if he come down, the Sprites are switching very fast.
Here is the code from the Character:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/12-ArRoYtUmrtqg2l5UR1Sebgkn6uiOZOJHPq9zjKF8Q
I hope you can help me to fix it :)

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. Please show **only the relevant code** directly here in the post. I can't even access your files there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I can't access your files so...Propably you need change colision mask for your character to static it means that there will be 1 colision mask for all images of your character. I recommend use rectangle or disk collision mask for character. To slow down animation just use `image_speed`